# delete all virtual environments with xargs rmvirtualenv

Tags: bash, xargs, virtualenvwrapper

I try to pipe lsvirtual to xargs like that:

```
 lsvirtualenv -b|xargs -0 -I env rmvirtualenv env
```

and it returns:

```
xargs: rmvirtualenv: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add output of `lsvirtualenv -b` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmvirtualenv` is not a script, it's a shell function created by `. virtualenvwrapper.sh`. You cannot call a shell function from `xargs`. You can try calling bash, sourcing `virtualenvwrapper.sh` and then calling `rmvirtualenv`. Or you can try

```
rmvirtualenv `lsvirtualenv -b`
```